# export data from MySQL database to excel in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export-to-csv

I am new to PHP. I just want to export data(the search result which I got from querying the database) to excel.
My problem is the data in excel will automatically change a new line. **I want 'cn' 'ai'... in the next column but not next line.**

I already removed all the `$csv_output .= "\r";` in my code.
So I thing there might be something wrong with my query statement:

```
$searchp = "
    select 
        * 
    from 
        insecticide a 
            LEFT JOIN crop b 
                ON a.ID = b.ID 
    where 
        a.Pestcide_trade_name like'%$tn%' 
        and a.Pestcide_trade_name like'%$tn2%' 
        and b.Crops like'%$crops%' 
        and b.Crops like'%$crops2%' 
        and a.AMW like'%$amw%' 
        and b.Pests like'%$pest%' 
        and a.Company_name like'%$cn%' 
        and a.Company_name like'%$cn2%' 
        and a.Active_ingredient like'%$ai%' 
        and a.Active_ingredient like'%$ai2%' 
        and a.PPE like'%$ppe%' 
        and a.PPE like'%$ppe2%' 
        and a.MMW like'%$mmw%' 
        and a.EH like'%$eh%' 
        and b.REI like'%$rei%' 
        and b.REI like'%$rei2%' 
    ORDER BY 
        a.Pestcide_trade_name ASC"
```

I am new to PHP and MySQL. Please give me some hint about this problem. Thanks!

```
<?php
    require_once("db.php");


                $tn = $_POST['TN']?$_POST['TN']:'';
                $tn2 = $_POST['TN2']?$_POST['TN2']:'';
                $cn = $_POST['CN']?$_POST['CN']:'';
                $cn2 = $_POST['CN2']?$_POST['CN2']:'';
                $ai = $_POST['AI']?$_POST['AI']:'';
                $ai2 = $_POST['AI2']?$_POST['AI2']:'';
                $ppe = $_POST['PPE']?$_POST['PPE']:'';
                $ppe2 = $_POST['PPE2']?$_POST['PPE2']:'';
                $amw  = $_POST['AMW']?$_POST['AMW']:'';
                $mmw  = $_POST['MMW']?$_POST['MMW']:'';
                $eh = $_POST['EH']?$_POST['EH']:'';
                $crops = $_POST['Crops']?$_POST['Crops']:'';
                $crops2 = $_POST['Crop2']?$_POST['Crop2']:'';
                $rei = $_POST['REI']?$_POST['REI']:'';              
                $rei2 = $_POST['REI2']?$_POST['REI2']:'';
                $pest = $_POST['PEST']?$_POST['PEST']:'';
                $rate = $_POST['RATE']?$_POST['RATE']:'';
                $note = $_POST['Note']?$_POST['Note']:'';
                $restrictions = $_POST['Restrictions']?$_POST['Restrictions']:'';    
        $searchp = "select * from insecticide a LEFT JOIN crop b ON a.ID = b.ID where a.Pestcide_trade_name like'%$tn%' and a.Pestcide_trade_name like'%$tn2%' and b.Crops like'%$crops%' and b.Crops like'%$crops2%' and a.AMW like'%$amw%' and b.Pests like'%$pest%' and a.Company_name like'%$cn%' and a.Company_name like'%$cn2%' and a.Active_ingredient like'%$ai%' and a.Active_ingredient like'%$ai2%' and a.PPE like'%$ppe%' and a.PPE like'%$ppe2%' and a.MMW like'%$mmw%' and a.EH like'%$eh%' and b.REI like'%$rei%' and b.REI like'%$rei2%' ORDER BY a.Pestcide_trade_name ASC";
        $result=mysql_query($searchp)or die(mysql_error()); 
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);
        mysql_close();

       $csv_output = '"Trade name","Company Name","Active Ingredient","PPE","Applicators Must Wear","Mixers Must Wear","Environmental Hazards","CROPS","REI","PEST","RATE","RATE","NOTE","RESTRICTION"\N';

            $i=0;
            while ($i < $num) {

            $tn1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Pestcide_trade_name");
            $cn1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Company_name");
            $ai1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Active_ingredient");
            $ppe1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"PPE");
            $amw1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"AMW");
            $mmw1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"MMW");

            $eh1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"EH");
            $crop1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Crops");
            $rei1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"REI");
            $pest1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Pests");
            $rate1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Rate_FL_OZ_ARCE");
            $rate11 = mysql_result($result,$i,"RATE_LB_ARCE");
            $note1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Note");
            $restrictions1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"Restrictions");

            $csv_output .= "$tn1";
            $csv_output .="$cn1";
            $csv_output .="$ai1";
            $csv_output .= "$ppe1";
            $csv_output .="$amw1";
            $csv_output .= "$mmw1";
            $csv_output .= "$eh1";
            $csv_output .= "$crop1";
            $csv_output .= "$rei1";
            $csv_output .= "$pest1";
            $csv_output .= "$rate1";
            $csv_output .= "$rate11";
            $csv_output .= "$note1";
            $csv_output .= "$restrictions1";
            $csv_output .= "\n";
            ++$i;
            }


    $filename = "results_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
    header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
    print $csv_output;
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: What you're doing here is extremely dangerous, taking unescaped user input and putting it *directly* into your SQL query. You should not be using `mysql_query` in any new applications because it's being retired, and further, it leads to code exactly like this, full of bugs and security problems. It doesn't take long to learn how to [escape SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) with PDO or `mysqli` and you'll be safe and secure from that point forward. Step one of learning how to use MySQL with PHP is learning how **NOT TO** use `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't write CSV code yourself. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Also, you're missing delimiters... but don't fix this code. Refactor it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the commas and the quotes:

```
        $csv_output .= '"' . $tn1 . '",';
        $csv_output .= '"' . $cn1 . '",';
        // etc.
```

Comment: Or `$csv_output .= "'$tn1',";`.